# How do I use a macro to run a custom sort on a specific group of data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

Ok so how would one go about making a macro that automatically runs every minute that sorts a set group of data via custom "layers" of data? For example it sorts column a that contains some numerical data from smallest to largest and then it sorts column b that contains more numerical data but it doesn't change the fact that there is already groupings in column a? Full example below

So we start off with some random data as seen here:

A | B

1 | 2

2 | 2

1 | 1

2 | 1

Then we see that the first layer of the sort has been executed here:

A | B

1 | 2

1 | 1

2 | 2

2 | 1

As seen in this last section the second layer of the sort has been executed within the sections defined by the first layer (So all the rows with a 1 in column A are still together and all the rows with 2 in column B are still together!)

A | B

1 | 1

1 | 2

2 | 1

2 | 2

How would one write a Macro to achieve this result and how would one adapt the macro to have 3 sorting layers (columns A, B, and C)?

The Data I need to sort is in columns A-N and the "Layers" that need sorting are in columns C, D, and G

Comment: Use the macro recorder as a starting point.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that [SU] is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Like teylyn stated, I think that's how we all learned VBa in the beginning. If you are using Excel 2016 and don't find the "recorder", you might not have the "Developer" tab visible. The default is hidden. To view it, File>Options>Customize Ribbon, check the box Developer (right side). Once this is done: think of a task you want done, hit record, perform the task, view the code, learn form the code, work with the code, look up solutions, then seek help at a sticking point once you've done some work.

Comment: I think you can accomplish that just using multi-column sort order.  Select both columns, select sort, choose A as the first and B as the second.  That takes you from the first table to the last.  If you need a macro, just record a macro that does that.  If you need more sort columns than are available, start at the right of the data and do the above pattern in successive passes on all of the data, moving the sort columns in groups to the left.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help but I found out how to do it! There is an option in excel to do a custom sort so I just used that!